# Closed but opened

Tags: riddle

> **Abstract Simultaneously** (Also known as *'Opened but closed'*)
>
> *Give me to someone,*
> *And I am closed,*
> *Wait for response,*
> *And open it goes.*
>
> *Words I have three,*
> *And everyone knows me.*
>
> *Though abstract, I am,*
> *If you agree,*
> *Anyone can use me,*
> *Does someone know: Who is this so-called 'me'?*

It might be a bit easy for some of you, but it's a 100% original one.

The answers can be a little different, but as long as the core answer stays the same, it's good.

Some information for line 7/8 (*Though abstract, I am, if you agree*):

> I **am** abstract, but I am **used** in the non-abstract place named *'The Universe'*.

And with the last line (*Who is this so-called 'me'?*) I mean: *What am I?*

EXTRA INFORMATION (Required for a 'good' answer)

> I may be abstract, but some theories say I am **both abstract and a type of *waves***.

HINT to speed up the process:

> Look at @can-ned_food's answer and the comments attached for a hint!

Comment: Is it three words or three letters !?

Comment: "And open it goes", is the line deliberately not fully grammatical?

Comment: 'It' referes to something a can't tell you because it would ruin it.

Comment: @DuncanWhyte , did you check the answers before add the new hint?

Comment: Of course?? What do you mean?

Comment: I'm quite convinced that my revised Vocal Cords answer is the best fit.  As Rubio described in the comment to my Q&A one, sometimes the desired answer is not always the best one.  Reality being a combination of multiple clusters and all that.  At the risk of sounding haughty — Don't get discouraged; good riddles take time to craft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a tripartite discussion; or, Question And Answer

---

> Give me to someone, And I am closed,
>
> > Giving an Answer closes, or ends, its three–part discussion.  Unless this is a Jeopardy! episode or the like, the Answer is preceeded by
>
> Wait for response, And open it goes.
>
> > A Question, which — unless it is phrased rhetorically — awaits a response and thus opens the discussion in a figurative sense.
>
> Words I have three, And everyone knows me.
>
> > Question And Answer 
> >  This is rather obtuse, and that's why I never wanted to proffer this prior.
>
> Though abstract, I am,
>
> > Such a Discussion, if it is done vocally, involves speech.  Speech, as a word, refers to both an utterance of phonemes and the meaning attached to them.
>
> Anyone can use me,
>
> > Speech is the concept abstracted of active methods and not a countable or particular thing.
>
> I may be abstract, but some theories say I am both abstract and a type of waves.
>
> > Sound waves.

I submit a different answer here because this one, although similar (parallel?) to the train of my first, proceeds from a very different premise.  Also, I'm really fond of the ‘vocal cords’ one; to be frank, I must also note that Communication et al can occur through media other than vocal speech.

Comment: there is no single "I" that matches everything.  "Question And Answer" has 3 words and is, I suppose, abstract; but you are not giving someone a "Question and Answer" to close the discussion - you're giving an answer - nor is Q&A a type of waves.  "Sound" is both abstract and a wave, and was referenced by OP as being "correct", but "sound" is not an answer to the first 3 clues at all.  With some ugly stretching you can argue that this answer is the closest fit for the question, but honestly there is no single answer that fits all the clues.

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

> love

Give me to someone,

> you can give love to another person

And I am closed,

> when you give a love letter it is a closed envelope

Wait for response,

> how does the other respond

And open it goes.

> you open the returning love letter

Words I have three,
And everyone knows me.

> I love you

Though abstract, I am,

> Love is an abstract concept

If you agree,
Anyone can use me,

> everybody can say I love you to another and love another person

Does someone know: Who is this so-called 'me'?

> you are love

Comment: Seems like it is something related to human interaction or communication, from the hint my first guess was 'Audio Cassette Tape' - Abstract, Opens & Three words :)

Comment: Communication? Correct! But how?

Answer (score 0):

Is it...

> **International Morse Code**

Give me to someone, And I am closed.

> When you first send it to someone, it is encoded hence closed.

Wait for response, And open it goes.

> But if they understand and reply, that opens up further communication

Words I have three, And everyone knows me.

> It's three words and most people know about it.

Though abstract, I am. If you agree, Anyone can use me.

> Anyone can start using it literally by knocking or tapping, as simple as that

Hint 1: I am abstract, but I am used in the non-abstract place named 'The Universe'.

> It is still a preferred method to communicate with an alien civilization

Hint 2: I may be abstract, but some theories say I am both abstract and a type of waves.

> The code itself is abstract but the medium for communicating it is light or sound waves.

Answer (score 0):

> vocal cords in the larynx, and the speech uttered thereby 
>  > previously:  speech

---

> Give me to someone, And I am closed,
>
> > When you speak, the vocal cords tighten or ‘close’ together so as to obstruct the airways. 
> >  > previously:  Here I take the use of ‘to close’ as being the malappropriated synonym for ‘to shut’, and by relation, ‘to end’.  A conversation is arguably ended when someone speaks,
>
> Wait for response, And open it goes.
>
> > When you cease speaking, the vocal cords relax and open the airway. 
> >  > previously:  until, that is, another person replies.  Vis à vis having the final word, et al.
>
> Words I have three, And everyone knows me.
>
> > Granted that for this one I needed to refer to a website, but [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocal_folds) gave three colloquial names for the things:  vocal folds, vocal cords, and voice reeds. 
> >  > previously:  “I am ‹name›.”  q.e.d.
>
> Though abstract, I am,
>
> > Speech is both an utterance of phonemes and the meaning attached to them?  That's one aspect of the concept of abstractness.
>
> If you agree,
>
> > (Forgive me for being so arrogant.)
> >  Alas, I would've phrased this differently, but I suppose you included the first line as rhetoric, and not as a condition for the sursequent statement:
>
> Anyone can use me,
>
> > Not a political affirmation, but because speech is something which can be  done by anyone able to do so, in that it is abstract and not a countable or particular thing.
>
> I may be abstract, but some theories say I am both abstract and a type of waves.
>
> > Sound waves?
> >  This is the best of my other two considerations, being ‘name’ and ‘hand’.  Honestly, if it weren't for this hint which you included, I would've chosen ‘hand’.

Because the new answer was almost the same as the previous, I chose to edit rather than make a new one.

Comment: Close! It's got to do with sound and speech. But the closed opened part is something else.

Comment: So close! Abstract is right, soundwaves is correct but the three words and the openclose part.

Comment: Think of this: you can SPEAK something thats CLOSED and when recieved something OPENS

Answer (score 0):

Are you:

> Silence?

Give me to someone,
And I am closed,

> Give someone silence and it exists

Wait for response,
And open it goes.

> If they respond, it does not.

Words I have three,
And everyone knows me.

> Not sure about the three but everyone knows silence

Though abstract, I am,
If you agree,
Anyone can use me,
Does someone know: Who is this so-called 'me'?

> Everyone can use some silence.

Answer (score 0):

Though the hint made me a bit confused, yet I'm pretty sure that you are:

> [Radio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio)

*Give me to someone,*

*And I am closed,*

*Wait for response,*

*And open it goes.*

> This refers to the sequence of using the [two-way radio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-way_radio):
>  
>  1. You need another two-way radio user to talk.
>  
>  2. A two-way radio is always closed if you doesn't use it at all.
>  
>  3. You can receive signal from the frequency that you had set-up, only if you are not opening the talking button.
>  
>  4. As the talking button is pressed, you can talk to anyone on the same frequency.

*Words I have three,*

*And everyone knows me.*

> Everyone knows about radio, but when it comes to the word, we may refer it as  a [*radio receiver*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_receiver) or an [*antenna*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_(radio)).

*Though abstract, I am,*

*If you agree,*

*Anyone can use me,*

> When it comes to the radio wave itself, it is either abstract or technical that people might not really understand. 
>  
>  However, we use it everyday on radio receivers, and devices like [walkie-talkie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walkie-talkie) or smartphones also included.

Answer (score 0):

How about this as an answer:

> Present

Give me to someone,
And I am closed,

> Present(Gift ) , when given to anyone, is closed, wrapped.

Wait for response,
And open it goes.

> Response is opening the gift

Words I have three,
And everyone knows me.

> Could it be three syllable? or present, gift, today

Though abstract, I am,
If you agree,
Anyone can use me,

> Probably playing with the two meanings of present i.e today and gift.

Does someone know: Who is this so-called 'me'?

> I guess present :)

Answer (score 0):

Or could it be:

> Tense

Give me to someone,
And I am closed,

> Present (Tense) or could mean gift which is closed.

Wait for response,
And open it goes.

> Response is opening the gift or it could also mean present (tense) becomes past when when you wait.

Words I have three,
And everyone knows me.

> Present, past, future.

Though abstract, I am,
If you agree,
Anyone can use me,

> Use present to etch a memorable past for a better future :)

Does someone know: Who is this so-called 'me'?

> I guess Tense :P

Answer (score 0):

You are

> A mind.

Give me to someone,
And I am closed,

> If you give someone (a piece of) your mind, you're telling them like it is and not interested in their opinion - you're closed-minded.

Wait for response,
And open it goes.

> When you want to hear what someone else has to say, you're open-minded.

Words I have three,
And everyone knows me.

> I'm guessing this is id, ego, superego

Though abstract, I am,
If you agree,
Anyone can use me,

> The mind is an abstract thing, a person's consciousness, not merely the physical matter of their brain. But everyone has one, and anyone can (and does) use their mind.

I may be abstract, but some theories say I am both abstract and a type of waves.

> Mind-waves.